# How do I use changepage for a webpage

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

For a mobile application, I can just go:

```
$.mobile.changePage("#home");
```

using the id.

What is the equivalent if I want to use it on a web page where I want to go to another page for example home.html?

Thanks for help.

Comment: `<a href="home.html"></a>`

Comment: `home.html` instead of `#home`.

Comment: I tried: $.mobile.changePage("home.html"); It doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use **[.pagecontainer()](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/)** instead since `$.mobile.changePage()` is deprecated as of version `1.4.0` and will be removed in `1.5.0`:

```
$(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", "home.html");
```

Comment: My current page is login.html so should I write it as follows cos it doesn't work.$("login.html").pagecontainer("change", "home.html");

Comment: @Trevor_zam, try $("body").pagecontainer("change", "home.html");, this assumes you are using jQM 1.4 and that home.html is in the same path as the current page.